# Django rest - how to write unittest code views functionality which has permission and viewsets

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework

Iam not writing any unit test code before. I'm really new into this. I need advice to write unittest code. I have two seperate folder for login and main functionalities also have seperate models in same db. In my login it will give response when i do test from POSTman. bt in my testcase it didnot workout. My login user should be in my db thats necessary.

```
Views.py
class LoginAPI(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("hello")
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        print(request.data)
        print(serializer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data.get('user')
        print("user 1")
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        login(request, user)
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        user.remote_addr = ip
        user.set_password(request.data['password'])
        user.save()
        print("user")
        return Response({"logged_in_user": {"token": token.key,
                                            "user_id": user.pk,
                                            "username": user.username,
                                            "employee_id": user.employee.id,
                                            "employee_name": user.fullname,
                                            "member_of": user.member_of,
                                            }
                         })
```

This is my test.py

```
class loginTest(APITestCase):

    def test_basic_auth(self):
        url = reverse('login')
        data = {"username": "HRMUEMPLOYEE1", "password": "$True*W0rk%32;"}
        resp = self.client.post(url, data=data, format='json')
        print(resp)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

When i gave same credentials from postman its working. but here its not working. it will through error not null constraint...
Any help Appreciable...

Comment: Here, I have got assertion error.. I dont know why????

Comment: You have to create the user with that credentials first, as your test is using a test database which would have no user. It's working in postman because you are using a different database

Comment: yes i am using different database how can i connect for my unittest. Bcz it based on ldap. so my testing should be in postgres db. how can i connect for unittest.

Comment: if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
            'USER': env('DB_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
            'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
        }
    }
I have given this for my settings.py file to connect db for testing. But it also didnot work